# Facet wrap, last facet expands to availible space

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Brief:** I have a faceted plot that is in a column, being split by each September 01.09.YY

**Problem:** The last facet, (year), if it is not the whole year, a few months, then the plot stretches out to take the whole space given. How to prevent that?

**Image:**
expected to get a cut off plot, instead the plot stretched out.
[image]

**Code:**
So here is the reproducible example.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(bbplot)
library(dplyr)
library(scales) 

results <- data.frame(
    name = rep(c("Sales", "osh", "staff", "salary", "Counterparties", "Taxes"), each = 18),
    total = c(
      900, 250, 300,   900, 250, 300,  900, 250, 300,  900, 250, 300,  900, 250, 300,  900, 250, 300,  
      -20, -20, -10,   -20, -20, -10,  -20, -20, -10,  -20, -20, -10,  -20, -20, -10,  -20, -20, -10,  
      -40, -45, -46,   -40, -45, -46,  -40, -45, -46,  -40, -45, -46,  -40, -45, -46,  -40, -45, -46,  
      -80, -60, -50,   -80, -60, -50,  -80, -60, -50,  -80, -60, -50,  -80, -60, -50,  -80, -60, -50,  
      -20, -90, -70,   -20, -90, -70,  -20, -90, -70,  -20, -90, -70,  -20, -90, -70,  -20, -90, -70,  
      -40, -20, -10,   -40, -20, -10,  -40, -20, -10,  -40, -20, -10,  -40, -20, -10,  -40, -20, -10
            ),
  month_date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2022-08-01"), by = "months", length.out = 18)
)

f <- function(date) {
  year <- lubridate::year(date)
  september <- as.Date(paste(year, "09-01", sep = "-"))
  if (date >= september) {
    year <- year
    nyear <- year + 1
  } else {
    nyear <- year
    year <- year - 1
  }
  return(paste(year, nyear, sep = "-"))
}

results <- results %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(year_range = f(month_date))

color_mapping <- data.frame(
  name = c("Sales", "osh", "staff", "salary", "Counterparties", "Taxes"),
  fill_color = c(
    "#518E51",
    "#5171A5",
    "#C7C7C7CC", 
    "#f0e68c",
    "#C9560E",
    "#B7153E" 
  ),
  border_color = c(
    "#294729",
    "#2D436C",
    "#9B9B9BCC",
    "#918413",
    "#C9560E",
    "#6E0D25"
  )
)

pos <- results %>%
  filter(total > 0)
bos <- results %>%
  filter(total <= 0) %>%
  mutate(total = -total)

border_color_named_vector <- setNames(color_mapping$border_color, color_mapping$name)

fill_color_named_vector <- setNames(color_mapping$fill_color, color_mapping$name)
half_transparent_fill_color_named_vector <- fill_color_named_vector
half_transparent_fill_color_named_vector[bos$name] <- alpha(fill_color_named_vector[bos$name], alpha = 0.6)
half_transparent_fill_color_named_vector["Sales students"] = "#518E51"
# 


just_the_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_area(data = pos, aes(x = month_date, y = total, fill=name, colour=name)) +
  geom_area(data = bos, aes(x = month_date, y = total, fill=name, colour=name)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = half_transparent_fill_color_named_vector) +
  scale_color_manual(values = border_color_named_vector)


faceted <- just_the_plot +
  facet_wrap(~ year_range, ncol= 1,scales = "free_x") +  # Faceting based on the year_range column
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  bbc_style()
faceted
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to remove the `scales="free_x"` from the facetting. Then you need to add another column, which represents just the month, without the year. You can either use the month number or the month name, I've chosen to use the lubridate pckage

```
library(lubridate)

pos <- pos %>% mutate(month_only = month(month_date))
bos <- bos %>% mutate(month_only = month(month_date))

just_the_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_area(data = pos, aes(x = month_only, y = total, fill=name, colour=name)) +
  geom_area(data = bos, aes(x = month_only, y = total, fill=name, colour=name)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = half_transparent_fill_color_named_vector) +
  scale_color_manual(values = border_color_named_vector)


faceted <- just_the_plot +
  facet_wrap(~ year_range, ncol= 1) +  # Faceting based on the year_range column
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) 
faceted
```

[image]

```
library(lubridate)

pos <- pos %>% mutate(month_only = month(month_date,label=TRUE))
bos <- bos %>% mutate(month_only = month(month_date,label=TRUE))

just_the_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_area(data = pos, aes(x = month_only, y = total, fill=name, colour=name, group = name)) +
  geom_area(data = bos, aes(x = month_only, y = total, fill=name, colour=name, group = name)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = half_transparent_fill_color_named_vector) +
  scale_color_manual(values = border_color_named_vector)


faceted <- just_the_plot +
  facet_wrap(~ year_range, ncol= 1) +  # Faceting based on the year_range column
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) 
faceted
```

[image]

Note that you need to add the group-aesthetic to the geom_area as you are dealing with a discrete x-axis when you are using month-labels.

EDIT: I had to remove the `bbbc_style()` as I cannot install packages right now

EDIT2: You have a datapoint for the january in the range 2023-2024. If I remove that point, the behaviour of the plot is as you described in your question, i.e. cut off:

[image]